# C Producer/Consumer application getting environment variables with getenv() not working

Tags: c, linux, environment-variables, getenv

I'm writing an application with Producer who makes and sends messages and Consumer who is getting the messages. I have to set environment variable in producer app and read it in consumer app.

In producer app I did this command

```
putenv("MSG_KEY=15");
```

And in the consumer app i tried to get the variable like this

```
char *z=getenv("MSG_KEY");
```

But it doesn't return any value (I get nil value). If I write the same command in producer it works if I use `putenv()` few lines before. I think the problem is that it sets variable only locally so I cannot access it from another program but I don't know how to solve it.
Don't know if it matters but I'm using Linux system.

Comment: More context please! Are you forking, or which mechanisms are used to start the asynchronous processing?

Comment: Please provide a link to the specification of that language C/C++. Until now, there are only two different languages C and C++. Pick one, learn [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: The environment is local to each process. `putenv` only affects the invoking process and its child processes.

Comment: Well, your primary problem is that even though they are on the same system, each one is running in its own environment.  You should really look at Inter Process Communication, socket based communication, a FIFO queue or something similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Environment variables are private to a process. You cannot set them in one process and expect to read them in another process.

The only time you can communicate anything via environment variables to another process is from a parent process to a child, and *only* at the time that the parent spawns the child. The parent may copy, modify, add, or remove environment variables when it spawns the child. From then on they become entirely separated. Change that one process makes to the variables, is not visible to the other.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Im quite new to this (and also didnt work with c++ for long time) and was totatly confused. Made some research from the things that you posted here and now I understand how it works.